# Does Crying often reduce body weight or become lean?

Tags: side-effects, body-weight, water-weight, tear-duct

Crying is one type of expressing feelings. Does crying often reduce the body weight or does it lead to become lean?  Is it affect the health?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, crying helps to reduce body weight.

Stress expert Dr Pete Sulack explained to PopSugar that your tears actually contain stress hormones, meaning that when you cry, you're reducing the levels of these hormones in the body.

This impacts weight loss because one of those stress hormones is cortisol, which is a hormone that also happens to make your stomach cling on to fat.


Now, to be clear, that doesn’t mean you can replace your gym trips with a forced crying session.

As Yahoo notes, studies have shown that only tears that are caused by genuine emotions – not faked tears or those induced by onion-chopping – contain stress hormones.

Read more: http://metro.co.uk/2016/07/23/theres-another-weird-benefit-of-having-a-good-cry-6024545/#ixzz4NzVpIsxw